# Anyone else seeing problematic 499 errors on mailgun?

Tags: smtp, mailgun

We are getting repeated 499 connection timeout errors on sending.  These are now accumulating and beginning to perm-fail.

Can anyone here suggest things to look at?  Have opened a ticket with Mailgun, but no response yet.

Sending through EasyDNS:

`Server response: 499 unable to connect to MX servers: - mx-caprica.easydns.com: connection failed: failed to dial: dial tcp4 184.173.153.222:0->64.68.200.41:25: i/o timeout`

And through Google, too

`Server response: 499 unable to connect to MX servers: - gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com: connection failed: failed to dial: dial tcp4 184.173.153.222:0->173.194.204.27:25: i/o timeout - alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com: connection failed: failed to dial: dial tcp4 184.173.153.222:0->64.233.186.26:25: i/o timeout - alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com: connection failed: failed to dial: dial tcp4 184.173.153.222:0->209.85.202.26:25: i/o timeout - alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com: connection failed: failed to dial: dial tcp4 184.173.153.222:0->74.125.140.27:25: i/o timeout - alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com: connection failed: failed to dial: dial tcp4 184.173.153.222:0->74.125.128.27:25: i/o timeout`

Comment: Looks like the mailgun shared IP address was blacklisted: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a184.173.153.222&run=toolpage

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the mailgun shared IP address that was assigned to our account had been blacklisted (not due to our traffic, I'm sure):

https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a184.173.153.222&run=toolpage

This caused the relaying MX servers to fail to connect.  We were able to manually reassign (by deleting the shared address from the account in the mailgun interface) to a different address and things started flowing again.

Mailgun support did not help us on this - so you may need to handle this yourselves if you are on their lowest tier and discover it happening.